# Conexão com banco de dados em java tem que ser somente por uma classe main?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Para fazer uma conexão com o banco em java, tenho que fazer somente através de uma classe main ou posso fazer através de outra classe??

```
public class ConexaoBasica {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("banco", "root", "");
        System.out.println(conexao);
        System.out.println("Conectado!!!");     
        conexao.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa, o recomendado é deixar ela em uma classe separada e fazer uma instancia dela ou fazer um método estático para recuperar a conexão, segue um exemplo de classe com um método para conexão no banco de dados.

```
public class SqlConnection
{
    public static Connection connect() {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste","teste","teste");  

        return con;
    }
}
```